# Form Autocomplete jquery actions not working

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, autocomplete

I have a checkout form with several add/remove classes and such based on filling out the form. However, when you select the autocomplete action, none of my jquery works--its as if the inputs don't recognize that text has been filled into them...what am I doing wrong? Here's my JS:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

$('input[type="text"]').focus(function(){

   $(this).closest('td').prev('td').addClass("bluebird");

     }).blur(function () {
       $(this).closest('td').prev('td').removeClass("bluebird");
   })

 $('input[type="text"]').keypress(function(){

 $(this).closest('td').prev('td').addClass("bluebg");

 }).blur(function () {
       $(this).closest('td').prev('td').removeClass("bluebg");

    checkFieldContentLength(this);
  });

$(this).on('keyup change click autocomplete', function() {
    checkFieldContentLength(this);
});

if ($(this).val().length > 0) {
     $(this).closest('td').prev('td').addClass("has-text");
}

function monitorAutocomplete() {
 $('input[type="text"]').change(function (type) {
checkFieldContentLength(this);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing I noticed was a missing ; for the focus event handler.

```
$('input[type="text"]').focus(function(){

$(this).closest('td').prev('td').addClass("bluebird");

 }).blur(function () {
   $(this).closest('td').prev('td').removeClass("bluebird");
})
```

Should be

```
$('input[type="text"]').focus(function(){

$(this).closest('td').prev('td').addClass("bluebird");

 }).blur(function () {
   $(this).closest('td').prev('td').removeClass("bluebird");
});
```

There is quite abit of missing information. If you provide a little more code, I can troubleshoot it quicker. If not, it may take me a little time to find a solution.